# Yii memcache session got invalidated after deployment

Tags: php, yii

Every time I deploy my Yii app, I change the symbolic link of the `/var/www`. Something similar like this

```
rm -f /var/www
ln -s /var/app-version /var/www
```

But every time I do this, the user sessions got invalidated (i.e. all of the users got logged out and CSRF tokens were reset).

For the session I use `CCacheHttpSession`. Something like below in the `main.php`

```
'components' => [
    'memcache' => [
        'class' => 'CMemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 11211,
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'WebUser',
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'CCacheHttpSession',
        'cacheID' => 'memcache'
    ]
]
```

I'm not sure whether this misconfiguration is in PHP-level or Yii-level, but what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `CCache` will use a [`keyPrefix`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#keyPrefix-detail) that contains [`Yii::app()->id`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getId-detail). This unique `ID` is calculated as a hash of the current `basePath` plus the `name` of the application. If you look at [`setBasePath()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#setBasePath-detail) you see, that it will use the [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php). This causes symlinks to be resolved to their origin.

So if the origin of your symlink changes, this will lead to a different application ID, which again leads to a changed cache key prefix. And this invalidates your cache content.

To fix this, you can either

- Set a static `id` on the application in your `main.php` configuration, or
- Set a static `keyPrefix` on your `memcache` component.

The latter is recommended anyway, if you have more than one server that all should access the same memcached pool.

Comment: So, that's why the `Yii::app()->user->getState()` got affected too. But if I choose the latter, I will still have to define `stateKeyPrefix` for `CWebUser` class, right?

Comment: [`setState()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail) is a wrapper around the session, which adds a [`stateKeyPrefix`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#getStateKeyPrefix-detail). The default key prefix also uses the Yii application ID. So yes, it may be safer to also set a static `id` on your application.

Comment: A little bit out of topic, what are the cases when we really have to change the application `id`?

Comment: There's no general rule, i think. But the situation you hit is definitely one. I had exactly the same issue with webistrano some time ago.

Comment: sorry to ask again, now the users didn't get logged out, but some CSRF tokens got invalidated. Did you experience the same?

Comment: Do you keep the contents of your `/runtime` directory? Yii uses the `securityManager` component to ensure validity of cookies. It therefore stores a `validationKey` in the global state. You can either keep the state file on deployment, or set a fixed `validationKey` on your `securityManager` component.

Comment: I have read the source code of CSecurityManager, but I didn't find a way to set the runtime directory into a different path.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's in the `CApplication`. I'll try setting up the runtime directory first. Since I use sticky-session for load-balancer, I guess this should be okay. But I will try setting a `validationKey` after that.